# how to bind closest li id to php variable

Tags: javascript, php

I want to get the closest id of the parent li and allocate it to a pre tag.
In a div, which surrounds the pre tag, there must be an onclick event with the same id.
What i have so far:

Adding the id to the pre tag from the parent li:

```
$('pre').each(function(){
          $(this).attr('id', $(this).closest('li').attr('id')+'_pre');
        });
```

The onclick event (i added this to a php variable)

```
$SelectButton = '<span class="control-copytextarea" onclick="return fieldtoclipboard.copyfield(event, \\\'id1\\\')">[Select and Copy]</span><br />';
```

Prepend just above the pre tag a span with the onclick

```
$('.surroundpre').prepend('$SelectButton');
```

The only thing i don't know how to achieve: in the php variable should **id1** also be replaced with the same id as already is added to the pre tag

Comment: try it with `'<?php echo $SelectButton; ?>'`

Comment: ofcourse i could echo this but the problem is how to replace **id1** with the same id as in the pre tag